# Surjective function has a right inverse

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, axiom-of-choice

We claim that if a function $f\colon A\to B$ is surjective, then it has a right inverse. We assume the Axiom of Choice, which states that given a family of nonempty subsets of a set, there is a way to choose one element in each member of the family.

Assume $f\colon A\to B$ is surjective. We will show that there exists $g\colon B\to A$ such that
$$f\circ g = id_B.$$
Consider first the family defined by
$$S = \{f^{-1}(q) \mid q\in B\}.$$
We will show that this is a family of nonempty, disjoint subsets of $A$.

Let $b \in B$ be arbitrary so $f^{-1}(b) \in S$. As $f\colon A \to B$, it follows that $f^{-1}(b)\subseteq A$.

As $f$ is surjective, there exists some $a\in A$ such that $f(a) = b$ so $a \in f^{-1}(b)$ hence $f^{-1}(b)$ is nonempty.

Finally, suppose there exist distinct $b_1,b_2 \in B$ such that
$$ f^{-1}(b_1)\cap f^{-1}(b_2) \not = \emptyset.$$
Then let $a\in f^{-1}(b_1)\cap f^{-1}(b_2) $ which leads to $b_1 = f(a) = b_2$, which contradicts the fact that $b_1$ and $b_2$ are distinct.

Consequently, $S$ is a family of nonempty, disjoint subsets of $A$.
Let $b \in B$. Then $f^{-1}(b) \in S$ so by the Axiom of Choice, there is a way to choose an element of $f^{-1}(b)$.

Call such a choice $a$. As $f^{-1}(b)\subseteq A, a\in A.$

Define $g\colon B\to A$ as $g(b) = a$ where $a$ is chosen as above. We will show that $g$ is a right inverse of $f.$ First, we will show that $g$ is a function.

Let $b\in B. $ Then such a choice exists thus every $b\in B$ has an image in $A$ under $g$. Since we choose exactly one element $a \in f^{-1}(b), $ it follows that this image is unique.

Finally, we have
$$f\circ g (b) = f(g(b)) = f(a) = b $$
as $a \in f^{-1}(b)$ and we are done.

This is the first time I have written a proof using the Axiom of Choice and while I think that my argument is correct, I am not very sure whether it is precisely written. Please see if my proof is correct and suggest ways to improve the clarity of the same.